# headerLeft issue of TabNavigator

Tags: react-native

Why my navigation does not display the icon that I've put on the header left parameter? It seems to me every thing is correct, the Icon is imported. Can you help to find the issue, here is my code:

```
const TabBarNavig = TabNavigator({
  Places  : {
    screen :AddPlaces,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Placements'
    })
  },
  GetPlaces : GetPlaces,
  New : New
});

TabBarNavig.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state: { routes, index } } = navigation; 
  const navigationOptions = {};
  navigationOptions.headerLeft = () => {
    return (
      <Icon 
        name = 'menu'
        size = { 20}
        color = 'white'
        style={{paddingTop:20}}
      /> 
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to put the icon on top of the tab itself, you will have to use StackNavigator

```
const TabBarNavig = TabNavigator({
  //your component here
})

const YNavigator = StackNavigator ({
  Home:{screen: TabBarNavig,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={20} color="white" />,
    })
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if use react navigation version 3 you must use `defaultNavigationOptions` instead of `navigationOptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
const TabBarNavig = TabNavigator({
  Places  : {
    screen :AddPlaces,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Placements'
    })
  },
  GetPlaces : GetPlaces,
  New : New
});
```

replace the **TabNavigator** with *createBottomTabNavigator*

```
const TabBarNavig = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Places  : {
    screen :AddPlaces,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Placements'
    })
  },
  GetPlaces : GetPlaces,
  New : New
});
```

I think this will solve your issue